# Transpose Article to Media (Image)

Tags: media

I am rebuilding a Drupal 7 site, making some changes to the data structure along the way. On the old site, I have a content type with an image, a description, and a couple other text fields. On the new site, I need this content to appear as images within a gallery (Media Gallery module). I also need to preserve the description field.

I'm not sure where to start. I used the Feeds module to migrate some other content types to their new versions, but that module cannot create this "Media" object, only nodes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Media Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/media_feeds) should allow you to create media objects that you can use in your gallery.

> **This module is the Drupal 7 solution for Media Feeds Integration.** It
>   provides mappers for the Feeds module. The target can be a Media
>   asset, image or file field on an entity (such as a node).